# Suspicious completionist up-votings

Tags: discussion

I've been the beneficiary (victim?) of a slew of badge-inducing up votes recently, receiving probably five or six Nice Answer and Enlightened badges in just the past week.

The random up votes are not surprising, since I get a lot of passive rep. But it sure seems weird that a whole bunch of accepted answers that had nine up votes suddenly, one or two a day, have been ripening into badge-producing fruit.

I'm just saying. If someone is gaming the system on my behalf, please stop. I don't need or want the help.

Comment: It's not gaming, it's OCD. I totally sympathize with it. Who can resist a +9? The badge is secondary.

Comment: I've also been an, um, beneficiary of such behavior recently, but I agree with Cerberus. In fact, I'd venture to guess that some of the people are doing it *only* because +10 looks so much better than +9, and they're not even aware that they're bestowing badges left and right.

Comment: I remember seeing a profile a few months ago where someone explicitly asked for other ELUers to at least consider upvoting that user's answers with 9 upvotes. I thought it seemed a bit odd, but it made me wonder if there weren't a few people on here that considered that a "polite" thing to do.

Comment: Glad to see I'm not alone. I got a whole bunch of badges for answers that had been sitting not just at 9 or 24, but at 8 or 23 for like a year.

Comment: +1 because 4 is a power of 2 and 3 is not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the voting is too suspicious, it will be automatically cancelled by the system, so you don't need to... well, worry.

If it's not, it will stay in place and in that case, congratulations for the badges. :P

Comment: Yeah, OK. I guess that's the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you had badges & rep. revoked, and your timeline doe not show it, then you only had 3 badges, 1 today, 1 a couple days ago, and 1 a month ago.  Hard to think that's suspicious.

Just lending some afterthought for future visitors.

Comment: Are you looking at his meta profile? His main site profile shows [a lot more badges earned](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/2303/robusto?tab=activity&sort=badges).